# iOS 7 GraphicsServices private API?

Tags: ios7, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi, cydia, theos

I'm developing Cydia tweaks using Theos.
I need to use some functions in the framework GraphicsServices.

I've tried some simple function using GSEvent. 
ex:

```
void GSEventVibrateForDuration(float secs);

void GSEventLockDevice();
```

But it all doesn't work. The device doesn't vibrate or lock. I'm using iPhone 5, iOS 7.0.4.
Then I found iOS 7 private frameworks on GitHub: https://github.com/EthanArbuckle/IOS-7-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework

Inside GraphicsServices is empty. So I'm wondering where this framework is? Sorry for my bad English, thank you!

Comment: GSEvent has mostly been replaced by IOHIDEvent on iOS 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of these headers in the internet are generated by class-dump, which only dumps Objective-C classes.

Purely C API's (like GSEventLockDevice) won't be dumped. You can use disassembler to look at them.

Some private API become protected by entitlements recently. This will produce exactly described behavior (do nothing when called).

Comment: Thanks, I see! but I want to ask one more question about developing tewak, My device is iPhone5, iOS7.0.4, I've tried to hook SpringBoard yesterday, but still many functions doesn't work. After that I discovered the headers I implement are too old (previous 7 version). So it cause many functions doesn't work, then I found iOS7 headers on github: http://goo.gl/gojTPr , I downloaded it and copy it to /opt/theos/include, it failed to make package, it says NSObject.h not found...
Which is the best way to implement iOS7 headers to theos? thank you!

Comment: You should just comment out #import "NSObject.h" and if any class is inherited from NSObject you can comment out this inheritance too. It's just a relict which is generated by class-dump.